# Multiple Domain SSL certificates for same server (ip address)

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, websphere-liberty

UseCase : We have Webapplication running in a server we like to access that application using different domain names i.e *.abc.com and *.xyz.com through  HTTPS.[we are using liberty server]

What we did :For that we have created CSR for *.abc.com and *.xyx.com and submit to CA and get the Certificates for both domain i.e *.abc.com and *.xyz.com.I have stored  both certificate in the Keystore and server ssl points to this keystore.

Issue : When we request our application i.e say Test.abc.com the certificate we got back form server is for *.xyz.com not *.abc.com both certificates are in the keystore why it is not recognize *.abc.com cert.when i request Test.xyz.com am getting the *.xyz.com certs i.e its only recognize one domain not multiple domain

Question: Is it possible to have multiple domain name  for same server.(i understand we can have wildcard for sub domains)

Comment: are required domains included in the certificate's Subject Alternative Names extension?

Comment: Thx for reply.But SAN Certificates we need to specify all the name used.in mycase i need *.abc.com and *.xyz.com each time if new  client is added we will create a sepearet name for them i.e entries to the domain say <newclient>.abc.com  or <neclient>.xyz.com

Answer (score 1):

You would need two https endpoints to choose between two certificates, and you'd have to arrange for connections to the right domains to arrive on the right/different local interfaces.  Liberty does not support TLS Server Name Indication (SNI) to choose a certificate based on data in the handshake.

Alternatively, you could frontend liberty with an https proxy that had SNI support.